# “Baffle” and “baffling”

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a good translation for the English “baffle”, as in:

> I am baffled by your inappropriate actions today!

I've found “*maldistingi*” and “*ŝoki*”, but they don't seem to have
quite the same.

Comment: "baffling" can, depending on the exact notion, be "nekomprenebla". (Not in every meaning and context, off course.) Not sure whether a matching word for the verb "baffle" can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vi povas uzi `konfuzi`<sup>*</sup> (ĉi tie povus temi pri mensoklareco):

> Kaŭzi la perdon de ies trankvileco, memcerteco, mensoklareco

aŭ, kiam temas pri iel senmoviga suprizo, `konsterni`<sup>*</sup>:

> Subite mirigi k timigi iun, farante lin/ŝin nekapabla agi aŭ paroli

`Konfuzi` subtrekas vian pluan emon (kaj ne eblon) kompreni.

`Konsterni` povas ankaŭ esti produkto de ŝoko, sen ia ajn volo (aŭ eblo) kompreni.

`Ŝoki`<sup>9</sup> povas esti taŭga, kaj ĝi ĉefe rilatas malplaĉon.

Almenaŭ tiujn tri eblojn vi havas, depende de la kuntekto kaj de tio, kion vi volas elstarigi.

Answer (score 1):

There also is the adjective *perpleksa* (recognizable is several languages), but *konsterni* in the sense of *miregigi* seems to be most versatile.

I am baffled by your inappropriate actions today!

> Mi estas **perpleksa** pro viaj maltaŭgaj agoj!

> Mi estas **konsternita** pro viaj maltaŭgaj agoj!

Comment: Interese. Oni tamen notu ke ĝi estas novradiko.